# How to update and delete comments in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am struggling with updating and deleting comments created by users, I have created Class Based Views for the comments but I am not sure how to proceed as I am getting errors

Are there any other options that users can be able to delete and edit their comments?

The error I am currently receiving is:

```
FieldError at /blog/sdsdssds/update_comment/
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: content, created, id, post, post_id, updated, user, user_id
```

Any ideas how to fix this error and what is the reason for it?

Here is models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300, validators=[validate_comment_text])
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostCommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = post
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))

class PostCommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']  # What needs to appear in the page for update
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False

class PostCommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/postcomment_confirm_delete.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
```

Here is the template:

```
            {% for comment in comments %}
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="media">
                    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ comment.post.author.profile.image.url }}">
                      <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{comment.user| capfirst}}<small class="text-muted">- {{ comment.created}}</small> </h5>
                        <hr class="solid mt-0">
                        {{ comment.content}}
                      </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
               {% if comment.user == user %}
                  <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'blog:post-commentu' post.slug %}">Update</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'blog:post-commentd' post.slug %}">Delete</a>
                  </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Here is the urls.py

```
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/add_comment/',
         PostCommentCreateView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/update_comment/',
         PostCommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-commentu'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/delete_comment/',
         PostCommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-commentd'),
```

Comment: We need to see your Post model to help.

Comment: @m.arthur I added the Post model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your slug field in your Post model, I think it's causing a collision.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug_field = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')
```

Comment: tried it but still same error... Creating a comment is working fine the issue is with Updating and deleting

Comment: is your url pattern capturing the slug?

Comment: Yeah, post your urls.py. You may need to use <slug:slug>

Comment: sorry just added the urls.py to question.

Comment: @devdrc I have updated the `slug=self.post.slug` but now showing the same error but highlighting the error from the `test` function `comment = self.get_object()`

Comment: @devdrc it messed alot of the project, but how will this help?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a slug into your Url although your Comment Model doesn't have one. What you need to pass into the url is the comment's unique id not the not the slug of the post it belongs to.